# `golangci-lint run` issue

Tags: go, lint

I create a `.golangci.yml` in working directory, which have more `linters` than default,  and run `golangci-lint run -v` but found linters are still default value, anyone encountered same issue? I have checked `.golangci.yml` path is correct. below is our configure value:

```
linters:
disable-all: true
enable:
  - bodyclose
  - deadcode
  - depguard
  - dogsled
  - dupl
  - errcheck
  - exhaustive
  - gochecknoinits
  - goconst
  - gocritic
  - gofmt
  - gomnd
  - goprintffuncname
  - gosec
  - gosimple
  - govet
  - ineffassign
  - interfacer
  - lll
  - misspell
  - nakedret
  - noctx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This yaml file isn't indented properly. try:

```
linters:
  enable:
    - bodyclose
    - deadcode
    - depguard
    - dogsled
    - dupl
    - errcheck
    - exhaustive
    - gochecknoinits
    - goconst
    - gocritic
    - gofmt
    - gomnd
    - goprintffuncname
    - gosec
    - gosimple
    - govet
    - ineffassign
    - interfacer
    - lll
    - misspell
    - nakedret
    - noctx
```

Comment: not caused by this issue as some others use same file but works,

Comment: What does `golangci-lint config path` returns ?

Comment: hi how can I get `golangci-lint config path`, I just created config file in working root directory. it's same as where I run `golangci-lint run -v` command

Comment: Just run `golangci-lint config path` and tell me what is the output

Comment: when I run `golangci-lint config path`, just return `.golangci.yml`, I think means current folder this file

Comment: This is weird. Are you are sure that `golangci-lint linters` doesn't show your linters enabled ?

Comment: can you show the output of `golangci-lint linters` as @aureliar mentioned

Comment: yeah wired, I checked by `golangci-lint linters` command, only 10 linters enabled but my yml linters are more than 20

Comment: Please run `golangci-lint run -v`. Is the second line `INFO [config_reader] Used config file .golangci.yml` ? If yes then your config file is likely invalid or doesn't actually do want you want

Comment: yeah I guess so, let me check .golangci.yml Grammer

Comment: but wired thing is that some guy git clone my file,  run `golangci run -v` locally and linters are expected, I use Goland, not sure if it affect

Comment: Maybe try to clean the cache ? `golangci-lint cache clean`

Comment: I got reason, indent issue, thank u so much